# Android View Model

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

If I call lets say some function A in init block of View Model which will update live data and after that I m observing this live data in onViewCreated of activity. Then it is correct or not.? It will get that value which is stored in live data? Or I have to call function A after observing live data in activity.

And if it is working why it will work?

Comment: You can try that out yourself. Let us know if you see any unexpected results.

Comment: @ArpitShukla I have already tried this. But it is working fine. I am asking if there is any problem faced by anyone using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

`LiveData` is just a data holder. It will store the latest value of the state.  If you call function A in the init block, the live data will probably get its value before you start observing it in your Fragment/Activity i.e. when you observe it, you will get the new value of live data updated by function A.
If you call function A after setting up the observer, you will probably see the initial value of the LiveData first and then the new value will be observed.

In either case, it doesn't make much of a difference, because the value set by function A will anyway be processed. But is you want to set the value of LiveData as soon as the Activity/Fragment loads, `init` block of the ViewModel is a good choice.

Also note that if you call function A from the Fragment/Activity, it will be called every time the view gets destroyed and recreated. So if you are doing some operation in function A which should not be repeated on every view recreation, ViewModel's `init` block is the only option here.